# iOS In App Purchase: can I make the "first one free"?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'd like to ship a paid application where the user has access to one of the in app purchases for free.

Assume I have a collection of city maps.  I'd like the user to pay $0.99 for the app and get *one* of the maps free, but have to pay $0.99 for successive apps.  However, I want to let the user choose which map they get for free rather than it being baked into the application.

Is there a way for IAP to support this?  Or do I have to build it outside of the framework?

Sanjay

Comment: In-App purchase work that you allow the user to load content from your server. Therefore you can let the user purchase the first map for free. But you have to think about how to identify the user.

Comment: This is exactly my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, once you want to give them a list of the maps and the one they choose they get. Make a NSUserDefault for every map and have the application check for that on startup.
If your application supports iCloud use an NSUbiquitousKey or even better, if you have a server, just have it store that their "account" has that map.

Hope it helps. (Comment if I missed the question completely, I feel that I might have misunderstood it). :)